# How to realise a mousewheel zoom function with pdf.js?

Tags: javascript, pdf, zooming, pdf.js

pdf.js seems to be a mighty but lousy documented tool. Anyone of you knows how to create a zoom function with it? I tried something but it doesn't work as expected. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oeaLzavn/2/

This is the code:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <canvas id="the-canvas" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
canvas{
    width: 500px;
    /* overflow: scroll; //didn't help */
}
```

javascript:

```
//jQuery and pdf.js needed
$(document).ready(function () {

    var url = "http://cdn.mozilla.net/pdfjs/tracemonkey.pdf";

    var pdfDoc = null,
        pageNum = 1,
        scale = 0.8,
        canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    function renderPage(num, scale) {
        // Using promise to fetch the page
        pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function (page) {
            var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
            canvas.height = viewport.height;
            canvas.width = viewport.width;

            // Render PDF page into canvas context
            var renderContext = {
                canvasContext: ctx,
                viewport: viewport
            };
            page.render(renderContext);
        });
    }

    PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(function getPdfHelloWorld(_pdfDoc) {
        pdfDoc = _pdfDoc;
        renderPage(pageNum, scale);
    });

    if (canvas.addEventListener) {
        // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
        canvas.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false);
        // Firefox
        canvas.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", MouseWheelHandler, false);
    }
    // IE 6/7/8
    else canvas.attachEvent("onmousewheel", MouseWheelHandler);

    function MouseWheelHandler(e) {
        var e = window.event || e;
        console.log(e);
        var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
        console.log(delta);
        if (delta == 1) {
            scale = scale + 0.2;
        }
        else {
            scale = scale - 0.2;
        }
        renderPage(pageNum, scale);
    }

});
```

Is scale the wrong parameter? Or is it just a css thing? Any ideas?

Comment: What problem are you seeing exactly? Is the pdf being rendered correctly when the page first loads?

Comment: First I was confused by your comment but then I checked the fiddle in chrome. Didn't even load the rendered pdf there... But the localhost script does. But if you use firefox for the fiddle you will see the problem. The rendered pdf loads, but when using the mousewheel over the canvas the content doesn't get bigger. Instead text from other pages will be seen on the current page. It's strange.

Comment: Yeah, it was confusing me as well :) Turns out the pdf.js external resource reference needed to be changed from https://raw.github.com/... to https://rawgithub.com/...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently setting the width to 500px of the canvas, which means that it'll always have a width of 500px. If you remove the width property it'll scale as expected.

You could add a width and height property on the parent container with overflow:scroll, so the user can move around the scaled canvas tag.

```
.container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: scroll; 
}
canvas{
    min-width: 10px;
    min-height: 10px;
}
```

[JSfiddle fork](http://jsfiddle.net/y8vv42ud/1/)

Comment: Thx but that's the thing. It should stay that size, but be scrollable. But overflow scroll had no effect...

Comment: Overflow scroll should be on the parent container

Comment: Thx. But still it's not working as it should. Sometimes lines from other pages are on the rendered page or sometimes the page content is inverted. But sometimes it works. It's just strange. Maybe I should just wait for a more stable version of pdf.js. Thx anyway!